# Split 'RockPaperScissors.Paper' string in vb.net to just retrieve 'Rock'

Tags: vb.net, string, split

The following code

`player2.getWeapon.ToString()`

returns

```
'RockPaperScissors.Rock'
```

OR

```
 'RockPaperScissors.Paper'
```

OR

```
'RockPaperScissors.Scissors'
```

I am just interested in the Class Name, i.e. Rock, Paper or Scissors. How can I achieve this?

Split was what came to my mind but not sure if its the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ToString` is just a regular overridable method defined by the base `Object` class.  Therefore, you can easily override it to make it return whatever you want.  For instance:

```
Public Class Rock
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return "Rock"
    End Function
End Class
```

Or, if you want to force your classes to implement it, you could do it in your base `Weapon` class, like this:

```
Public Class Weapon
    Public Sub New(weaponName As String)
        _weaponName = weaponName
    End Sub

    Private _weaponName As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return _weaponName
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Rock
    Inherits Weapon

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("Rock")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to require it in the constructor, you could add a protected `MustOverride Function GetWeaponName() As String` in your base class and then return that from `ToString`.  Either way, the derived classes will be forced to provide the name so that it can be returned in `ToString`.

The reason I recommend doing it this way is because I suspect you are using this string as a description which is displayed to the user.  If that's the case, it's not really the class name that you want, but a description of the weapon.  So far, they just happen to be the same, but logically speaking, that's not alway going to be the case.  For instance, if you had a class called `SuperDuperRock`, you aren't going to want to display it like that to the user.  Rather, you'd want it to be properly formatted with spaces between the words.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) seems to be the appropriate way:

```
Dim tokens As String() = player2.getWeapon.ToString().Split("."c)
Dim className As String = tokens.Last() ' or simply tokens(1) without Linq
```

But if you can extend your `Weapon` class with a property that returns it directly i would do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you really do not wish to use Split() you could use IndexOf (more performant)

```
Dim className as String    
Dim weapon = player2.getWeapon.ToString()
Dim pos as Integer = weapon.IndexOf("."c)
if pos >= 0 Then 
    className =  weapon.Substring(pos + 1)
End if
```